# Dropbox files in another location to norm

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

I use dropbox and very happy with it.

The only drawback I have with it is that I must place the files I want to share in the My Dropbox folder.

Is there anyway I can place the files in another folder on my PC and automatically sync between dropbox folder and another folder on my local pc?

Comment: Which OS  ? Windows ?

Comment: Yes Windows 7 Professional. Meant to include that!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a symlink to 'mirror' the contents of one folder with your Dropbox.

Open a command prompt or terminal. On Windows (I think starting from XP) you can use the command `mklink.exe` to achieve this, on Linux systems you can use the command `ln -s`. I'm not familiar with the commandline arguments by mind but you can look up the syntax with `mklink.exe /?` or `man ln`, or use Google. :P

You can also move the Dropbox folder to a different location in the settings but you will not be able to rename `My Dropbox`.

Comment: `mklink /d "<path to alternate folder>" "<path to>\My Dropbox"`  (You have to run the command prompt as Administrator)

Comment: BTW, this command has been available since Windows 2000, although it was called `linkd.exe`.  They reworked it, and renamed it, as of Windows Vista.

Comment: I've done this and it's been great for Dropbox.

Comment: Thanks raven. (I usually mix up the two, usually resulting in an error so I have to switch the two folders xD)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but it requires that you have a filesystem in NTFS format. You'll need an external tool, [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/HardLinkShellExt_win32.exe) to make links and drop it as junctions.

So the steps are:

- Install Link Shell Extension
- Browse to any folder you’d like to link with `My Dropbox`. Right click on the folder and select `Pick Link Source`.
- Goto the location where `My Dropbox` is and right click it and select `Drop As..` => `Junction`.
- Thats it. Now open `My Dropbox` and you'll see that there's a new folder named `Junction to`, click it and you'll see the exact copy of the files/folders you had in the source location.
  Now just keep working on those folders and they’ll keep syncing to your Dropbox.